# Can I import a library in zapier code

Tags: python, zapier

Is there a way to import a library in Zapier Python Code?
Specifically, I want the 'datasift' library.

When I try, I just get "ImportError: No module named datasift"

Comment: Yes you can as long as you have installed it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the zapier documentation, it specifically says that it only allows for the `requests` import and standard python imports

Answer (score 0):

We can import only requests, so we need to find another way to run any python code which include the other libraries.
Maybe, we can build python to exe file and run it directly by zapier service.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).