# Using a webhook to pull specific data into a Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, stripe-payments, zapier

I basically need to pull new cancellations from customers but the data that is pulled via the webhook does not contain the customer name or email in association with the cancellation request. The product name is also hard to find.

So I can add "customer.Updated" to the list of events to watch for, but it creates two separate rows in the webhook. I cannot pull data from one result and concatenate it with the other cancellation result.

I created a webhook to pull "customer.subscription.deleted" and "customer. Updated" and it creates separate rows for each.

I can't grab both and export what I want in Google Sheets.

I then tried using Zapier code and doing it via Python:

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = "HAVEAPIKEYPUTINHEREBUTLEAVINGITOUT"

def get_customer_info():
    subscriptions = stripe.Subscription.list()
    for subscription in subscriptions:
        if subscription.status == "canceled" and "Consistency Club" in subscription.plan.product.name:
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(subscription.customer)
            print("Customer Name:", customer.name)
            print("Customer Email:", customer.email)
            print("Subscription Cancelled At:", subscription.canceled_at)
            print("Subscription Cancel Reason:", subscription.cancel_reason)

get_customer_info()
```

It says the Stripe module doesn't exist. I added it as the type of connection I want and then the code afterwards, still get the same thing.

My goal is to pull the following listed in the Python code above. Create a new row in Google Sheets Workbook for any new cancellations coming in.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "It says the Stripe module doesn't exist" seems to be a specific Python issue, maybe you can share details on your Python version and error message.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track.  You need to get the webhook, then fetch the additional information you need from the Sripe API.

I don't know a lot about Zapier's ability to run code, but it sounds like they don't have [the Stripe Python library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python) installed, and it seems like [there's no way to install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444956/can-i-import-a-library-in-zapier-code).

The alternative is to make the API requests directly without using a Stripe library.  You can look at [Stripe's API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl) at the curl examples to see how to make the raw requests, then translate those into Python code you can run in Zapier.